# Should I add yarn-error.log to my .gitignore file?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Yarn has created `yarn.lock` and `yarn-error.log`.

I have been told not to add `yarn.lock` to my `.gitignore` file because it locks down the packages.

Should I ignore the latter?

Comment: The yarn documentation recommends checking in `yarn.lock`, but that's not really your question, so I'd just take that part out and simplify the question, IMO.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It makes sense to **ignore the `yarn-error.log`**—log files are only useful to debug your *own* copy of the code, so there's no need to upload it to the repository.

File should be uploaded to your repo when they are *useful* or needed to build your project. The `yarn-error.log` (as the name suggests) is an **error log**, so it's never read by Yarn. The whole point of it is that **you** read the log to find out what went wrong, and if you've not had any errors, it might not even exist at all.

[gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/), a service which generates `.gitignore` files, include `yarn-error.log` and `yarn-debug.log` in their [`.gitignore` file for Node](https://www.gitignore.io/api/node):

```
### Node ###
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

It may be wise to follow their example if you're not sure what you need—most pre-made `.gitignore` files have thought this issue through and concluded that logs **should** generally be ignored.

Comment: To add to this, make sure that yarn.lock however, is not ignored. yarn docs state this. https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm

Answer (score 2):

Since writing this I realise all log files are typically ignored in the .gitignore file with this entry:

```
*.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Its system specific log file for the user. So it should be added to gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

some times we find error that is  "cannot find symbol"  when build the project.
to solve that problem we add this file to our root project.

we can use it in our project where all all files and folder are available.

just above to yarn.log file